# Babel 6 error "Using removed Babel 5 option"

Tags: babeljs

I'm requested to write a new app using some modules from the old one. We'd like also to test a transition to Babel 6 for the old app.

I have two .babelrc, one wrote for Babel 5 in an upper directory and the other for Babel 6 in a sub directory:

```
├── .babelrc       # babel5 config
├── app
│   └── foo.js     # should work with both babel5 and babel6
└── new_app 
    ├── .babelrc   # babel6 config
    └── bar.js     # import ../app/foo.js
```

When I run Babel 6 from the sub directory, it throws an error:

```
Using removed Babel 5 option etc
```

So I tried to add `breakConfig: true` and it throws another error:

```
This is not a necessary option in Babel 6
```

Is there a way with Babel 6 to skip parsing upper configs as it was with Babel 5 using the `breakConfig` option?

Comment: What specifically is your structure? Babel 6 should stop at the first `.babelrc` it finds

Comment: thanks i've updated the question showing the file structure.